# Checking error page webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling

If something goes wrong with the website, error page appears with a stack trace, and this text has a WebElement. When the site is down, I can locate the errorTrace element and log the error.

However, the site is UP and running, the errorTrace element is hidden, I got NosuchElementException but it should go on because we have no error. How can I handle this situation when something can happen, but not necessary!

```
@FindBy(id = "someId")
private WebElement errorTrace;

    try {
       errorTrace.isDisplayed();    
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.error("Unexpected error appears: \n" + errorTrace.getText());
    }
```

I would like to implement some common method, when something happening with the site, handle it properly. So fail the test only, when the errorTrace element is available in the DOM.

Comment: Can you show us what is `errorTrace` ? What do you mean by `it is failing`? Does it shows any error? What does the error says? Update the Question with error stack trace.

Comment: updated, hopefully I clarified your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `if(!errorTrace.getText().contains("Stack Trace"))`

Or check if a title in the page is not same as that of a title of the error page.

Comment: You did not get it. This code is working fine, I can locate the error, but if the errorTrace element is not displayed, the test is failed. If it appears, I can handle with it properly. Main question is the if expression then continue logic, not what you mentioned.

Comment: I understand you want to wait untill the erroTrace element is available in order to read the content.                                                                         
Try using something like below:                                                                                                             
           (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));

Comment: Why should I wait if the error is not the expected result? I need a solution if it happens, handle it, if not, just go on. WebdriverWait will fail.